# Python - how to import class form another python file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

i have two files test.py and site.py in c:\newfolder. I want to import siteElements class from site.py to test.py.....I have written

```
from site import siteElements

siteElements = SiteElements(webdriver)
```

but its not working.....

> ImportError : cannot import name 'siteElements'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mismatch, what you should do is this:

```
from modulefile import classname
variable_object = classname(something)
```

Instead, it seems you do:

```
from modulefile import classname
classname = variable_object(something)
```

If we assume that you spelled the class correct, your code should read:

```
from site import siteElements
variable_object_name = siteElements(webdriver)
```

Alternatively you can do this like this, introducing an alias to the imported class (make sure the alias name is unique):

```
from site import siteElements as se
variable_object_name = se(webdriver)
```

You did not post the "site" module, so you need to check that `siteElements` is indeed the correct name/spelling of your class.